# Scroll bar in tbody cannot functioning well

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to add a scrollbar in the tbody of class applicant-info, but my code doesn't work well. It scrolls the whole applicant-info class. I want to access the tbody in certain class, but I don't know how.

Here is the coding:

```
  <style>
    .container {
      font-family: Mukta, sans-serif;
      height: 100vh;
      display: grid;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      color: #fffff;
      font-size: 0.9rem;
      background-color: #f9fbff;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #e1e5ee;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    thead {
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #e1e5ee;
      background-color: #daf0f7;
    }

    th {
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
      font-size: 0.7rem;
      font-weight: 900;
    }

    td {
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
    }
    .applicant-info {
      max-height: 400px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

  </style>
```

The html:

```
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">UPLOAD FILE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DETAILS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CLASSIFICATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SHORTLISTED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ANALYSIS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="job-info">
        <h2>Job's Information</h2>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Experiences</th>
              <th>Education</th>
              <th>Certifications</th>
              <th>Skills</th>
              <th>Languages</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for row in jobdata %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row[4] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row[5] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row[6] }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="applicant-info">
        <h2>Applicant's Information</h2>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Experiences</th>
              <th>Education</th>
              <th>Certifications</th>
              <th>Skills</th>
              <th>Languages</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for item in data %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ item["Name"] }}</td>
              <td>{{ item["Title"] }}</td>
              <td>{{ item["Location"] }}</td>
              <td>{{ item["Experiences"] }}</td>
              <td>{{ item["Education"] }}</td>
              <td>{{ item["Certifications"] }}</td>
              <td>{{ item["Skills"] }}</td>
              <td>{{ item["Languages"] }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    <br><br>
    <form action="/classify_data" method="POST">
      <button type="submit">Classification</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This coding scrolls from header 2, Applicant's Information. But I want to add the scroll only for the body of the table while the header is fixed and not being scroll together.